# SublimeText3 cannot find Python modules (numpy) installed with MacPorts

Tags: python, numpy, sublimetext3

I installed Python 3.5 using MacPorts.  I am trying to use SublimeText3 as an editor.  (Anything better and more integrated tan ST3 for python development??)

From the MacOSX terminal, I can 'import numpy' just fine, but SublimeText3 cannot find the packages.

Is it because the python packages are installed as 'Frameworks'?, because the Path for finding those modules is not right?, other????

Here's what terminal shows:

```
$ type -a python3
python3 is /opt/local/bin/python3
python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Here's what ST3 shows:

```
File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/python_work/array_play.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy

ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]

[cmd: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/xxx/Desktop/python_work/array_play.py']]

[dir: /Users/xxx/Desktop/python_work]

[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin::/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3/site-packages]
```

As you can see, I tried to add

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

to the Path variable, since this is the location of the numpy folder, but this doesn't work...

Should I just ignore this message in ST3 and use it only as an editor???  Seems rather silly to have an IDE and not be able to build and run programs from it...

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find out which python3 you are using in terminal. You can do this by running command `which python3`. Suppose the output is: `/Users/username/.anaconda3/bin/python3`.

Second, try to set PYTHONPATH environment variable in Sublime's settings. Go to `Preferences -> Settings User`, and add the following lines at the end of the settings file (but inside of the last `}` symbol).

```
"env":
{
    "PYTHONPATH":"/Users/username/.anaconda3/bin"
}
```